# How to hyperlink a select tag which open in a new tab and carry some variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new in PHP. i want to open a new tab when user click on option tag of a select tag. But i failed. Please help me.

Here is my Code

```
echo '<select name="sector_study_data" id="sector_study_data" STYLE="width: 300px">';

echo '<option value="">[--Select Sector Study2----]</option>';

    if(is_array($sector_study ) && !empty($sector_study ))
    {
        foreach($sector_study  as $sector_study)
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$sector_study->ID.'" href="update_sector_study.php?id='.$sector_study->ID.'"
            "target="_blank"">';

            //echo '<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">$sector_study->name</a>';

            echo $sector_study->name;

            echo '</option>';
        }
    }

echo '</select>';
```

Comment: I dont think it work this way, you need to listen for onchange event of select tag and then redirect user from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here using jquery you can achieve your requirement:

1 add url into data-href property of all options:

```
echo '<select name="sector_study_data" id="sector_study_data" STYLE="width: 300px">';
echo '<option value="">[--Select Sector Study2----]</option>';

    if(is_array($sector_study ) && !empty($sector_study ))
    {
        foreach($sector_study  as $sector_study)
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$sector_study->ID.'" data-href="update_sector_study.php?id='.$sector_study->ID.'">';

            //echo '<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">$sector_study->name</a>';

            echo $sector_study->name;

            echo '</option>';
        }
    }
echo '</select>';
```

using jquery:

```
$("#sector_study_data").change(function(){
  var href = $('option:selected', this).attr('data-href'); // get href of selected option
  window.open(href, '_blank'); // redirect to that href in new tab
})
```

Comment: is it showing any error in console? can just put generated html  select tag over here?

Comment: Its not showing any error but it also not opening a new tab.

Comment: Is there can i use onchange?

Comment: in that case you need to create function.. I have updated my code before few minute ..you can try that again

Comment: Just check your html, it is in same format as jsfiddle or not?

Comment: Yes.. I found my error. I use `die;` in my code. If u remove `die;` from my code its working but it also display my all data in multiple

Comment: "display my all data in multiple"? not getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111092/discussion-between-sunny-and-dhara-parmar).